# Loop through an Array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Angular is connected to node.js which fetch the data from mongodb.
This works fine, but now I need to map the variables in typescript component to the backend node.js.

in the browser console the data structure looks like this:
[Browser Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uoS8.png)

```
The code within the component.ts looks like this:
ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getContacts()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);

          let temp_max = res[0]['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_max)
          let temp_min = res[0]['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_min)
          let alldates = res[0]['list'].map(res => res.dt)

          let deviceData = []
          alldates.forEach((res) => {
            let jsdate = new Date(res * 1000)
            deviceData.push(jsdate.toLocaleTimeString('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }))
          })
          console.log(deviceData)
        })
  
}
```

now I wrote `let temp_max = res[0]['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_max)`, but how can I replace [0] with "i", what is the correct syntax in typescript?

I tried (code below) and get an error:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getContacts()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        for (var i = 0; res.length; i++) {
          let temp_max = res[i]['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_max)
          let temp_min = res[i]['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_min)
          let alldates = res[i]['list'].map(res => res.dt)

          let deviceData = []
          alldates.forEach((res) => {
            let jsdate = new Date(res * 1000)
            deviceData.push(jsdate.toLocaleTimeString('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }))
          })
          console.log(deviceData)
        })
      }
}
```

Please help me out :) with my problems. Thanks Eden

Comment: `and get an error` What's the error?

Comment: review your `for` condition, if there is any item in your array you'll get an infinite loop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The end condition of your loop is partially missing :

```
for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop `res` and then `list` to achieve this no need of any for loop.

```
const temp_max = res.map((r) => r.list.map((list) => list.main.temp_max));
const temp_min= res.map((r) => r.list.map((list) => list.main.temp_min));
const alldates = res.map((r) => r.list.map((list) => list.dt));

console.log(temp_max, temp_min, alldates)
```

Comment: thanks Kamran! yeah this is a great idea how to map the variables

Comment: If it works then can you accept this answer please?

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget the forEach can have an iterator as well:

`res.forEach((resItem, i) => {`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to stackoverflow. Instead of only suggesting to use something, it would be more better that we would have given a working solution of the question in this case.